# How do I change in-built themes?

Tags: beamer, templates, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [beamer: Create own headline theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38208/beamer-create-own-headline-theme)

I'd like to change the frame title of the `Berlin` theme in latex to be similar to the `Singapore` theme (fade out color). Is there a way of accessing the code for the Berlin and Singapore theme so that I can edit theme directly?

I have used the beamer user guide, but it's a bit slim as far as creating/editing themes goes. Is there a comprehensive guide/list for theme creation/editing, with all the `\setbeamerxxxx` and `\beamerthemexxxx` commands?

Comment: Have a look at [Gonzalo's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38208/3235) or modify a copy of the theme file.