# Where to find the documentation to beamer elements?

Tags: beamer, themes

I am on the way to create/customize a beamer template. Therefore I read the relevant chapters in the beameruserguide.

I think I understood the basic idea behind the theme setup and the use of the `\setbeamer***{}{}` commands.

There is always spoken of `some beamer element`. Yes, there are some examples, what could be used as these elements, but I do not see a list of all relevant elements reachable by default.

Also some commands seems not to be documented in the user manual (I did not find for example `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty`).

Where are such things documented or is there only a learning by doing way to understand things (in dozens of years)?

Comment: An *unhappy* answer is to look through the `beamer.cls` and its various `.sty` files.

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` is in the manual (page 72), `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` is probably old code that is not documented anymore. I'm working on my own template as well, googling was the best way for me to find out about certain things.

Comment: Try the cheat sheet described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85439/custom-headline-in-latex-beamer/85443#85443

Comment: you can find the code for the themes in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way.

You can find the code for the themes in `/.../tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/` (`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/`)

`\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` is in the manual (page 72), `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` is probably old code that is not documented anymore.

Or try the cheat sheet described in [Custom headline in LaTeX Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85439/custom-headline-in-latex-beamer/85443#85443)

As a last resort, you can look through the `beamer.cls` and its various `.sty` files.