# LaTeX Beamer Warsaw Theme Custom Headline Horizontal ToC

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I'm using beamer with the Warsaw theme to create a presentation. Now I want to change the header to display the sections and subsections next to each other instead of below each other.

The usual Warsaw theme:

[image: vertikal]

What I'm looking for:

[image: horizontal sections]

The respective subsections should be displayed in the blue stripe on the right.
So actually the original theme only has to be changed from vertical to horizontal display of the sections and subsections.

I found this code that partly does what I'm looking for. But then the subsections will disappear.

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
```

[Custom headline in LaTeX Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85439/custom-headline-in-latex-beamer)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `compress` beamer option:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\section{titlea}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{titlea}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it works only when I remove the custom color. How can I use both [compress] and [xcolor] at the same time? \documentclass[compress][xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme[named=MidnightBlue]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: @Toffee `\documentclass[compress,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
`

Comment: @Toffee You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Comment: @Toffee You should also not load the same package more than once