# Custom Beamer headline locally, reset to null height after

Tags: beamer, themes, headline

I want a custom headline for my introduction only.

Unfortunately, about controlling the height of the **headline** element, the Beamer
manual says:

> The size of the headline and the footline is determined as follows:
> Their width is always the paper width. Their height is determined by
> tentatively typesetting the headline and the footline right after the
> \begin{document} command. The head of the headline and the footline at
> that point is “frozen” and will be used throughout the whole document,
> even if the headline and footline vary in height later on (which they
> should not).

It should show the logical progression like this (I made the banner with Inkscape):

[image]

[image]

The current code used to manage that:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% From the manual, the headline content is necessary to compute the height of
% the headline for all the document, and is not expected to change.
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{banner-intro-dummy-0}
        }
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Life}
\subsection{The universe}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{banner-intro-dummy-2}}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tcolorbox}{Bla bla}\end{tcolorbox}

    \vspace{.5\baselineskip}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}

    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{column}
\pause
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
    % ...
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\subsection{And everything}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{banner-intro-dummy-3}}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]%
{example-image-a}

\end{column}
\pause
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
    % ...
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\section{No headlines here}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here are the banner images:

- [banner-intro-dummy-0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjgxA.png) (Just a transparent banner of the right size)
- [banner-intro-dummy-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lifzs.png)
- [banner-intro-dummy-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyomn.png)

So, the hard part is how to *stick a graphics to the very top of the frame*, while consuming vertical space for it? It should ideally allow for frame titles below. The banner blocks could be subsection titles, in which case a pure Beamer solution ([similar to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85439/95423)) would likely be better.

P.S.: my real world document uses the metropolis theme.