# Customization of the Copenhagen theme

Tags: beamer, formatting

I am preparing slides for my zeroth review (Project) using LaTeX. Now, I am very much appealed by this theme: [image: theme image]. The theme's link is given here: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211111142041/https://latex.simon04.net/). But, It is not available. I got the base theme `Copenhagen` but now I need to customize it to the colors and gradients applied in the theme. How do I do that? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are many subquestions answered on the site. Can you break it down to a few little questions? For example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38208/beamer-create-own-headline-theme

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Customizing a `beamer` theme might require a considerable amount of work, since a theme involves a lot of elements and unfortunately just a singlr frame dosen't give enough information about all the elements involved in the theme.

Below I present an option which produces a similar result for the elements showed in the image attached to the question.

Initially I took Copenhagen as the starting point (see "initial version" below), but the code is shorter if one takes `Warsaw`:

### Shorter version (using the `Warsaw` theme)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}

    \definecolor{myblue1}{RGB}{35,119,189}
    \definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{95,179,238}
    \definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{129,168,207}
    \definecolor{myblue4}{RGB}{26,89,142}

    \setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=myblue1,bg=blue}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

    \setbeamercolor*{item projected}{fg=red,bg=myblue3!80}
    \setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=white,bg=myblue4}
    \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=black}

    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
      color(0pt)=(myblue2);
      color(\paperwidth)=(white)}

    \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mysplit theme}
    {%
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill
        \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0.5em}
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother

    \title{The title of the paper}
    \author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \section{Propositional Argumentation Systems}
    \subsection{Propositional Logic}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Logical consequences}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item First.
      \item Second.
      \item Third.
    \begin{exampleblock}{Entailment Relation}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item First.
      \item Second.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{exampleblock}
      \item Fourth.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \subsection{Argumentation Systems}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Logical consequences}
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Probabilistic Argumentation Systems}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Logical consequences}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Argumentation Systems on Set Constraint Logic}
    \begin{frame}
    test
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

### Initial version (using the `Copenhagen` theme)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\definecolor{myblue1}{RGB}{35,119,189}
\definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{95,179,238}
\definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{129,168,207}
\definecolor{myblue4}{RGB}{26,89,142}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=myblue1,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{item projected}{fg=red,bg=myblue3!80}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=white,bg=myblue4}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mydefault}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,
  enlarge right by=-\beamer@rightmargin,
  width=\paperwidth,
  nobeforeafter,
  interior style={
    left color=myblue2,
    right color=white
    },
  shadow={0mm}{-0.4mm}{0mm}{black!60,opacity=0.6},    
  shadow={0mm}{-0.8mm}{0mm}{black!40,opacity=0.4},    
  ]
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    \insertframetitle\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mysplit theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Propositional Argumentation Systems}
\subsection{Propositional Logic}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\begin{exampleblock}{Entailment Relation}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
  \item Fourth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Probabilistic Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}

\section{Argumentation Systems on Set Constraint Logic}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there are other elements of the theme that you want to modify, please open a fresh new question focalizing on the specific element.

As a final note, in the link provided, one can see that this theme was designed for the Theoretical Computer Science Research Group of the University of Fribourg, Switzerland, and the link provided there is broken. There might be copyright issues with the theme, so you might well check first to see if there's no legal problem in producing and using this theme; in fact, if you contact the group, you could directly ask them for the source files for the theme.

Comment: +1 for asking the authors of the theme; I've seen cool themes for beamer and the authors are usually very coorporative when asked for the source files.