# Unable to change the color of frame title

Tags: beamer, formatting

This question is related to this post: [Customization of the Copenhagen theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/customization-of-the-copenhagen-theme).

I am unable to change the color of the frame title to white. 
I tried:  `\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

 \usetheme{Copenhagen}

 \definecolor{myblue1}{RGB}{35,119,189}
 \definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{95,179,238}
 \definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{129,168,207}
 \definecolor{myblue4}{RGB}{26,89,142}

 \setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=myblue1,bg=blue}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{item projected}{fg=red,bg=myblue3!80}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=white,bg=myblue4}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mydefault}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,
  enlarge right by=-\beamer@rightmargin,
  width=\paperwidth,
  nobeforeafter,
  interior style={
    left color=myblue2,
    right color=white
    },
  shadow={0mm}{-0.4mm}{0mm}{black!60,opacity=0.6},    
  shadow={0mm}{-0.8mm}{0mm}{black!40,opacity=0.4},    
  ]
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    \insertframetitle\par%
    {%
  \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
  \else%
  {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
  \fi
}%
\vskip-1ex%
\if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mysplit theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Propositional Argumentation Systems}
\subsection{Propositional Logic}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\begin{exampleblock}{Entailment Relation}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
  \item Fourth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Probabilistic Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}

\section{Argumentation Systems on Set Constraint Logic}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to illustrate the component(s) you want to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\definecolor{myblue1}{RGB}{35,119,189}
\definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{95,179,238}
\definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{129,168,207}
\definecolor{myblue4}{RGB}{26,89,142}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=myblue1,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{item projected}{fg=red,bg=myblue3!80}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=white,bg=myblue4}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mydefault}[1][left]
{
\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
\nointerlineskip%
\@tempdima=\textwidth%
\advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
\advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
boxrule=0pt,
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,
enlarge right by=-\beamer@rightmargin,
width=\paperwidth,
nobeforeafter,
interior style={
  left color=myblue2,
  right color=white
  },
shadow={0mm}{-0.4mm}{0mm}{black!60,opacity=0.6},    
shadow={0mm}{-0.8mm}{0mm}{black!40,opacity=0.4},    
]
  \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}%
  \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
  \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
  \insertframetitle\par%
  {%
\ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
\else%
{\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
\fi
}%
\vskip-1ex%
\if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
\end{tcolorbox}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mysplit theme}
{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0.5em}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Propositional Argumentation Systems}
\subsection{Propositional Logic}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\begin{exampleblock}{Entailment Relation}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\item Fourth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Probabilistic Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}

\section{Argumentation Systems on Set Constraint Logic}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But this is what I did, entering \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}, and it does not work for the Copenhagen theme (there are 2 themes in the related post). Moreover when I create a new document with the code you provided, I get strangely that all frames have their title in white except for the first one. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alan Please add a MWE

Comment: @Alan Please see my edit.

Comment: @ samcarter Thanks once again but I don't see the difference between your edit and the code I posted, and the frame title is still black. Best

Comment: @Alan the difference is the `\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}`

Comment: Thanks very much for you patience! I'm new at LaTeX and still learning