# Adding More Sections

Tags: formatting

I am new to latex and find a bit hard to customize beamer template. Can you please explain how to add more than two sections(like the ones in the example Proportional argument systems and Argumentation systems on set constraint logic) and make it displayable.

Reference post to this question - [Customization of the Copenhagen theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/customization-of-the-copenhagen-theme/373979?noredirect=1#comment924846_373979)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. This is not a typical Q&A site, so you should show what you have tried with a Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 0):

Going based off of the accepted answer to [the question you referenced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/customization-of-the-copenhagen-theme/373979?noredirect=1#comment924846_373979), I think all you are asking is for this:

```
\section{This is a new section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sk8forether added this section}
\end{frame}

\subsection{And this is an added subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sk8forether added this too}
\end{frame}
```

Which is how you would add a new section or subsection.  Using the complete example in the accepted answer, with my new section and subsection at the end, it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\definecolor{myblue1}{RGB}{35,119,189}
\definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{95,179,238}
\definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{129,168,207}
\definecolor{myblue4}{RGB}{26,89,142}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=myblue1,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{item projected}{fg=red,bg=myblue3!80}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=white,bg=myblue4}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mydefault}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  enlarge left by=-\beamer@leftmargin,
  enlarge right by=-\beamer@rightmargin,
  width=\paperwidth,
  nobeforeafter,
  interior style={
    left color=myblue2,
    right color=white
    },
  shadow={0mm}{-0.4mm}{0mm}{black!60,opacity=0.6},    
  shadow={0mm}{-0.8mm}{0mm}{black!40,opacity=0.4},    
  ]
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    \insertframetitle\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mysplit theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Subham Soni \and Sakthivel \and Syed Rabbani}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Propositional Argumentation Systems}
\subsection{Propositional Logic}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\begin{exampleblock}{Entailment Relation}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
  \item Fourth.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Probabilistic Argumentation Systems}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Logical consequences}
\end{frame}

\section{Argumentation Systems on Set Constraint Logic}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{This is a new section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sk8forether added this section}
\end{frame}

\subsection{And this is an added subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{sk8forether added this too}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please keep in mind this is copied from the question you linked, so most of it was already written for you.  I hope this helps you get started.